# Putting the refence to an instance along with the instance in a list

Tags: python, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

This is one of those "I think the answer in no, but I will ask anyway" questions.

I need to pass a list of tuples to a worker thread.
What I have right now:

```
Worklist[0]=('Read','Float','GagArray',Gagarray,200)
Worklist[1]=('Write','Int','Oiler',Oiler,1)
Worklist[2]=('Wrtie','BOOL','Buckets',Buckets,250)
...
```

Gagarray is a list of numbers (in this case floats).
My worker thread needs both the Name Gagarray and Gagarray.
My worker thread will use the string 'GagArray' to request data from a device.
The received data (in this case 200 floats) will be put into the GagArray list.

This works but the redundant 'GagArray' and GagArray bothers me.

I would like to do something like:

```
Worklist[0]=('Read','Float','GagArray',200)
```

The worker would have the string 'GagArray' and use that to reference the GagArray list.
ie:

```
Element=Worklist[0][2]
^Element^[3]=3.14159
```

PS. All the references will be in the scope of the worker thread. (Globals)

I think that this is a little different than the standard pass by reference question.

Comment: So, python isn't call by value, it's call by object reference, so you are always passing references... but your question is something different. Can you show us your code so we can see the scope of the `Gagarray`, `Oiler` etc. lists?

Comment: For now GagArray,Oiler,ect are globas. (I may clean that up later). For what it is worth, I don't think it is possible in C either.

Comment: Well, you could have your worker lookup `globals()['GagArray']`. Here is [an example of `globals()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/globals-function.html)... but it would be preferable to avoid global variables. Why not create a dictionary like `{'GagArray': GagArray, ...}`?

Comment: globals()['GagArray'] seems the cleanest except there will be a large number of globals. Making the dictionary is still redundant. ( Worse actually because now I have to type GagArray three times. Once in Worklist and twice in the dictionary ;-)

Comment: @2rs2ts: "So, python isn't call by value" It is exactly call by value. What you described is call by value.

Comment: @newacct Correct me if I'm wrong but the underlying CPython implementation is going to be passing references around, so it's call by reference; the caveat is that since (pretty much) everything is an object it's a bit of a special case and a lot of people call it "call by object reference." Call by value means that the value of the parameters is copied, but in this case only the references are copied (like in C). Or am I wrong about CPython?

Comment: @2rs2ts: Every value in Python is a reference (pointer to an object). That value is copied when passed or assigned. It's exactly the same as in Java and C, where it is called pass-by-value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values of global variables with `globals()` and the name of the variable.

```
Worklist[0]=('Read','Float','GagArray',200)
Worklist[1]=('Write','Int','Oiler',1)
Worklist[2]=('Wrtie','BOOL','Buckets',250)

GagArray = gobals()[Worklist[0][2]]
```